# Delegation from 'grandchild' view

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have a UIView that presents a tableView in a Popover. This tableView then presents another tableView with selectable data.  Could someone please explain to me how rouse delegation to get the selected data all the way back to the UIView? I initialize the 2nd tableView and set it's delegate to 'self' when I present the popover.  But when I actually do to use the delegate in the 2nd tableView, it is set to null.

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like:

TopMostView.h

```
@protocol ParentViewDelegate
-(void) operateOnData:(NSObject *)data;
@end

@interface TopMostSubview <ParentViewDelegate>
...
```

in TopMostView.m

```
-(void)crateSubview {
... create subview stuff
subview.delegate = self;
...
```

}

Then in each of the subviews have something like:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ParentViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Whenever you wish to pass data to the superview, you use the operateonData: selector.

Comment: Thanks @BigYellowCactus, but it is still not working. Here is my code in my TopMostView.m                                    `(IBAction)button:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender{
    if(!self.popover){
        Picker *picker=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Picker"];
        self.popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
        picker.delegate=self;
       //init popover
    }
}`                                                                                                                When I print the delegate in picker, it is set to null.